# Null-reference-exception-in-xamarin-forms-for-iOS and it works fine in Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

XAML Class:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XYZ.UI.CustomControls;assembly=XYZ.UI"xmlns:controls="clr- namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Controls;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Labs"
         x:Class="XYZ.UI.Views.Layouts.GHeaderLayout">
  <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="0">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="80" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,0,10,0" >
  <Label Text="{Binding CName}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="14" />
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0">
    <Label Text="{Binding JName}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="14"></Label>
    <Image Source="drp_btn.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="15"  ></Image>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer
         Command="{Binding OSCommand}"/>
  </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="End" Spacing="1">
  <Label x:Name="UserTotalHeader"  Text="Total" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" Font="14"></Label>
</StackLayout>



<StackLayout x:Name="GEPHeader"   Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0">
  <Grid RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="80" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    <StackLayout StyleId="A" x:Name="PNameLayout" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >


      <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <local:ItemsSourceBehavior StyleId="C" ItemsSource="{Binding PName}" Orientation="Horizontal" Scroll="Horizontal" >
        <local:ItemsSourceBehavior.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate >
            <StackLayout StyleId="D" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" >
             <Label Text="{Binding UD}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  XAlign="Center" Font="14"  TextColor="Gray" HeightRequest="40" FontFamily="Bold" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
              <Label Text="{Binding UnitCode}" XAlign="Center" Font="14"  TextColor="Gray" HeightRequest="40" FontFamily="Bold" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </DataTemplate>
        </local:ItemsSourceBehavior.ItemTemplate>
          </local:ItemsSourceBehavior>
      </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>

  </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

ItemsSourceBehavior :Its Giving NullReference Exception in IOS (Working fine in Android) LayoutChildren method which is inherited from Layout. I feel the crash happens just before calling the LayoutChildren method.

```
namespace XYZ.UI.CustomControls{ 
public class ItemsSourceBehavior : Layout<View>
{

  protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {

        try {
            if (layoutWidth == 0)
            {
                layoutWidth = width;
            }


            double rowHeight = 0;
            double yPos = y, xPos = x;

            foreach (var child in Children.Where(c => c.IsVisible))
            {
                //var request = child.GetSizeRequest(width, height);

                //double childWidth = request.Request.Width;
                //double childHeight = request.Request.Height;
                //rowHeight = Math.Max(rowHeight, childHeight);

                //if (xPos + childWidth > width)
                //{
                //    xPos = x;
                //    yPos += rowHeight + Spacing;
                //    rowHeight = 0;
                if (Children.Count < 4)
                {

                    var region = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, layoutWidth / Children.Count, 80);
                    LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(child, region);
                    xPos += region.Width + Spacing;

                }
                else
                {

                    var region = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, layoutWidth / 4, 80);
                    LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(child, region);
                    xPos += region.Width + Spacing;
                }

            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:ex{0}", ex);
        }}}
```

Output Window:

Resolved pending breakpoint at 'ItemsSourceBehavior.cs:362,1' to void XYZ.UI.CustomControls.ItemsSourceBehavior.LayoutChildren (double x, double y, double width, double height) [0x00000].
Thread finished:  #6
The thread 'Unknown' (0x6) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Thread finished:  #7
The thread 'Unknown' (0x7) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
2016-08-09 19:08:32.542 XYZ[4960:26908] 
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.LayoutChildren (Double x, Double y, Double width, Double height) [0x00092] in :0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout () [0x000c7] in :0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated (Double width, Double height) [0x0000f] in :0

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

## used by your application.

Launch succeeded. The app  'XYZ' has been successfully launched on 'iPad 2 iOS 8.4'.
The app has been terminated.

Comment: Please update your question with the output this the SIGABRT with the exception that it is throwing.

Comment: Can you please update how do you get this error? On what action, event, etc.

Comment: Use this tutorial to capture details of UnHandled Exception - https://peterno.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/unhandled-exception-handling-in-ios-and-android-with-xamarin/

Comment: @Rohit I have updated the code please check it when u have free tym.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I have updated code....

Comment: @PoojaRawat Please attach the error image in your question

Comment: @ParthPatel I have just updated Exception file also